# Javascript: Simplified RegEx for non-expression into capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to use a simplified RegEx to solve a little emoji replacement.

regex is: `((?!http)(\:\/))`

context is: 
`Hello there, don't goto <a href="http://x.com">x.com</a>, they have bad service :/`

Still captures both ":/"s in the context. I know there's the bracket non-capturing character method, but I couldn't find any modernized / simplified version of something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use lookbehinds you may want to try and cleverly expand your match like I.e.

```
( :\/)
```

Note the extra space which could of course be something more sophisticated.

**Update**

```
(:\/)(?!\/)
```

did the trick by using a negative lookahead (which Javascript supports) for a `/`.

Comment: Yeah problem with the space ahead is that it's too broad

Comment: How about \s for any whitespace character?

Comment: I was actually able to solve it by just including the non capturing expr afterwards for a secondary "/".